# JPA, Maps and insertion order

Tags: java, orm, jpa

My google-fu is failing me in this. I'm doing a small database app which reads some data from a file along with some meta data that I currently store in a Map in my entity. I'm getting fed up with it always being displayed in a random order.

So can I use a LinkedHashMap or @OrderColumn with Maps somehow to preserve insertion order?

```
@Entity
public class MooData
{
    @OrderColumn
    @ElementCollection
    private List<BigDecimal> data;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String, String> properties;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with using a linkedhashmap? And what order do you want?

Comment: @kasten - It's a couple of weeks since I tried this, but when I declared it as a LinkedHashMap (or was it TreeMap) JPA got really cranky and said it wanted a Map. Is it supposed to work? :)

Comment: I' sorry I don't know jpa and using a linkedhashmap seemed to fit :(. After some googling it seems that the concrete Hashobject isn't created by your code but the providers code. Another idea may be to use a OrderBy but someone else will be better suited to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't find any evidence in the JPA 2.0 spec that the `@OrderColumn` annotation is supposed to work for `Map`. Quoting the spec:

> #### 11.1.39 OrderColumn Annotation
>
> The `OrderColumn` annotation specifies a
>   column that is used to maintain the
>   persistent order of **a list**. The
>   persistence provider is responsible
>   for maintaining the order upon
>   retrieval and in the database. The
>   persistence provider is responsible
>   for updating the ordering upon
>   flushing to the database to reflect
>   any insertion, deletion, or reordering
>   affecting the list. The `OrderColumn`
>   annotation may be specified on a
>   one-to-many or many-to-many
>   relationship or on an element
>   collection. The `OrderColumn`
>   annotation is specified on the side of
>   the relationship that references the
>   collection that is to be ordered. The
>   order column is not visible as part of
>   the state of the entity or embeddable
>   class.

If you want to preserve order, use a `List` (of `Embeddable` in your case). With a `Map`, access to values by keys.

Comment: Kind of suspected that. I'll rewrite it as a List then :) Cheers Pascal

Answer (score -1):

My google-fu pointed me to some pages, where they say that `@OrderColumn` can be used for all collections - so it sounds like it's not restricted to lists or sets. Although all of the pages I found so far have examples with `List` fields.

The [eclipse WIKI](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/OrderColumns) has a nice article on the `@OrderColumn` annotation.

---

**Edit**

What about a workaround - you could add a method to your bean to get the maps entry set:

```
public Set<Map.Entry<?,?>> getPropertiesEntries() {
   Set<Map.Entry<?,?>> result = new TreeSet(myComparator);
   result.addAll(map.entrySet());
   return result;
}
```

and use this entrySet whenever you loop through the map.

Comment: Maps dont inherit the Collection interface which is is what I think a requirement for the @OrderColumn

Comment: If yourself found out that this is a wrong answer, maybe better to remove it